# Classic ASP and .Net Com DLL website hangs on concurrent requests

Tags: asp-classic, iis-10, com+

The website hosted in IIS 10, website developed using Classic ASP and .Net Com DLL.

.Net dll registered by following comment

`RegAsm.exe XXXX.dll /codebase`

Website work fine when single user access the website but when multiple user give the concurrent requests then site starts loading.... and no response received, it's loading until we close the browser window.

When the website has long loading.... in one browser(chrome), if I tried same website in another browser(firefox) it's working normally but in chrome it's still loading...

I have verified log details there is No updates in iis log files, but we have logs for other requests until loading issues came

There is no updates in httperr file.

If we restart the IIS it took some time to restart and got the following WAS warning in system event log,

`A worker process '####' serving application pool 'XXXXXXXX' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.`

Comment: How high is the CPU usage when multiple requests are initiated at the same time? I suspect it may be related to code optimization.

Comment: CPU usage looks normal. If I request same page in different browser it works fine.

Comment: Do you mean this problem only occurs when using chrome?